# Setting background color for AdControl in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

Is there any way to change the background color for the ad control banner in Windows Phone 8? The background color property or the border property doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue.
As a work around I created a rectangle with the background color and positioned it where my ad control is.
You may have to set the z index and set the margins on your page to accommodate it but it will give the same result as changing the ad controls back ground.

Here is my XAML code:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Width="480" Height="85" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Black"/>
    </Grid>
```

and the c# for the ad control:

```
AdControl adControl = new AdControl(APPLICATION_ID,   // ApplicationID
                                            AD_UNIT_ID,       // AdUnitID
                                            true);            // isAutoRefreshEnabled
        adControl.Width = 480;
        adControl.Height = 80;
        adControl.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(adControl);
```

I hope this helps, I'd be interested to hear any other solutions if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started to use AdDuplex which is much more straight forward and produces it's own container.